# loop on my quiz id and get each one and inserted in the answer table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the question id and insert it into the answer table every time the `$qid` insert into the database `1`

this is my db table look like

```
┌──┬───┬─────┬───┬────────┐
│id│uid│ad_id│qid│answer  │
├──┼───┼─────┼───┼────────┤
│1 │2  │15   │1  │Answer 1│
├──┼───┼─────┼───┼────────┤
│2 │2  │15   │1  │Answer 2│
├──┼───┼─────┼───┼────────┤
│3 │2  │15   │1  │Answer 3│
├──┼───┼─────┼───┼────────┤
│4 │2  │15   │1  │Answer 4│
└──┴───┴─────┴───┴────────┘
```

now the column `qid` should be the question id coming from the question table but it dose not as you see it's always insert `1`

this is my PHP code

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" id="quiz" class="container width_648">

<?php
            $getTheQuiz = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM rec_employer_quiz WHERE ad_id=?");
            $getTheQuiz->bind_param('i', $ad);
            if ($getTheQuiz->execute()) {
                $res = $getTheQuiz->get_result();
                $i = 0;
                while ($q = $res->fetch_array()) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="oneLine">
                        <div class="question">
                            <h3><?php printf("%s", $q['question']) ?></h3>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>" name="qid" id="qid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="answer">
                            <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid" value="<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>">
                            <textarea name="answer[]" rows="3" maxlength="200" class="message1 width_640"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <div class=" oneLine">
                    <input type="submit" name="ans" id="ans" value="I'm Finished" class=" MainBtn">
                </div>

                <?php
                $dateApplied = date(date_default_timezone_get());
                if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
                    //$questionId=$_POST['qid'];
                    foreach ($_POST["answer"] as $key => $answer) {
                        $questionId=$_POST['qid'];
                        $answer = $_POST["answer"][$key];
                        $putData = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rec_employer_quiz_results (id, uid, ad_id, qid, answer, exam_date)VALUE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, FROM_UNIXTIME(?))");
                        $putData->bind_param('iiiiss', $id, $uid, $ad, $questionId, $answer, $dateApplied);
                        if ($putData->execute()) {
                            echo "done";
                        } else {
                            printf("Error: %s\n", $db->error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        </form>
```

What I am getting now is the last question `id` for all the answers
I need to insert the id of the question with it's value.

**edit**

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" id="quiz" class="container width_648">


        <?php
        $getTheQuiz = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM rec_employer_quiz WHERE ad_id=?");
        $getTheQuiz->bind_param('i', $ad);
        if ($getTheQuiz->execute()) {
            $res = $getTheQuiz->get_result();
            while ($q = $res->fetch_array()) {
                ?>
                <div class="oneLine">
                    <div class="question">
                        <input type="hidden" name="qid[<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>]" value="qid[<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>]">
                        <h3><?php printf("%s", $q['question'])?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="answer">
                        <label for="answer"></label>
                        <textarea name="answer[]" id="answer" rows="3" maxlength="200" class="message1 width_640"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class=" oneLine">
                <input type="submit" name="ans" id="ans" value="I'm Finished" class=" MainBtn">
            </div>


            <?php
            $dateApplied = date(date_default_timezone_get());
            if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
                $questionId = $_POST['qid'];
                foreach ($_POST["answer"] as $key => $answer) {
                    $answer = $_POST["answer"][$key];
                    $putData = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rec_employer_quiz_results (id, uid, ad_id, qid, answer, exam_date)VALUE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, FROM_UNIXTIME(?))");
                    $putData->bind_param('iiiiss', $id, $uid, $ad, $questionId, $answer, $dateApplied);
                    if ($putData->execute()) {
                        print_r($_POST);
                    } else {
                        printf("Error: %s\n", $db->error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </form>
```

I am getting this on `print_r($_POST);`

```
Array
(
    [qid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
            [5] => 20
            [6] => 21
            [7] => 22
            [8] => 23
            [9] => 26
        )

    [answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Answer 
            [1] => Answer 2
            [2] => Answer 3
            [3] => Answer 5
            [4] => Answer 6
            [5] => Answer 7
            [6] => Answer 8
            [7] => Answer 9
            [8] => Answer 10
            [9] => Answer 11
        )

    [ans] => I'm Finished
)
1
```

but when check the inserted `qid` in my database it just insert `1` for all the rows.

Comment: You have a lot of fields with the same name `qid`. How do you think - is it right?

Comment: Yes I understand same as the `answer` what I am asking how to add the `qid` to the loop like the `answer`

Comment: I am getting the `answer` value from each `textarea` and inserting it to the `answer` in my db column can't I do the same for the `qid` for each question.

Comment: $_POST['qid'] won't ever be set.

Comment: @syslogic can you please give me hint why it won't ever be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider your code here:

```
<div class="question">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>" name="qid" id="qid">
 </div>
 <div class="answer">
    <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid" value="<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>">
    <textarea name="answer[]" rows="3" maxlength="200" class="message1 width_640"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here you already have 2 fields with name `qid`. After you `post` all fields from your form the last `qid` value will be saved. Also I don't understand why do you need 2 `qid` fields for each question? One field is not enough?

What you need to do is to set `qid` as `answer`, i.e

```
<input type="hidden" name="qid[]" id="qid" value="<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>">
```

`Print_r` you `$_POST` values then and see how are they arranged.

Going further you can use current `$q['id']` as part of field name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="qid[<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>]" id="qid" value="<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>">
```

And for answer too:

```
<textarea name="answer[<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>]" rows="3" maxlength="200" class="message1 width_640"></textarea>
```

Again `print_r` you `$_POST` values then and see how are they arranged.

Sidenote: `id` attribute for fields should be unique for each field.

**Update**:
so, I see you get proper qids. You should now use the same keys from `qid` and `answer`:

```
foreach ($_POST["answer"] as $key => $answer) {
    $answer = $_POST["answer"][$key];
    $questionId = $_POST['qid'][$key];
    // do insert
}
```

Comment: about 2 fields with name qid I was wrong about this I forgot to remove the other one and I updated the code as you said but still I am getting the same result one `qid` for all the answers which is not what I want I want to set for each answer the question id I will edit the question for you to see.

Comment: it comes '26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26' from `print_r($questionId);`

Comment: I don't need `questionid`, I need `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: it should be something like '1 2 3 4 5 ....' based on the question `id` coming from the database

Comment: OK `Array ( [qid] => 26 [answer] => Array ( [0] => this is anset [1] => saldjhaskl [2] => lkjklj [3] => lkjlkjlkj [4] => lkjlkjbh [5] => ,mbn [6] => ,mb, [7] => mnk [8] => hkl [9] => lkjhlkjl ) [ans] => I'm Finished ) `

Comment: Check code and html for your form, if you edited then `qid` key should be array, not string like now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64546/discussion-between-mikky-and-u-mulder).

Comment: Thanks for reply again but now I got this notes `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: Again here's some strange issue. If your html fields generated using `name="qid[<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>]"` there will be no zero key, as id can't be zero. And your `print_r` is invalid, check keys once again, or remove `<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>` part from ``name="qid[<?php printf("%s", $q['id']) ?>]"``